# How to run Docker container and watch the logs in one single command

Tags: docker

Right now, I run the following commands to see the logs of my image:

```
> docker run <my_image>
4985a657ee273afec4d3b6047a93016e83f36b20bf86429048c306658cf8cb49
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                  NAMES
54ea6e6834dd        hub:latest          "/sbin/my_init"     16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         3003/tcp, 5984/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2224->2222/tcp   romantic_curie   
> docker logs -f 54e
```

Is there a parameter I can add to see the logs right away? Something like docker run  --SOME_PARAMETER

Comment: You might also be interested in docker-compose, `docker-compose up` will give you the desired behaviour plus you don't have to remember any run arguments. win/win :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this : `docker run XXX && docker logs $(docker ps -lq)`

Answer (score 3):

Just `docker run xxx ;  docker logs $(docker ps -lq)` it means you want to see the logs of the last launched container